# Ci reflection formula

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, contour-integration

It appears that for all $\text{Re}(z)>0$, we have

$$\pi - i \text{Ci}(2\pi-iz)+i \text{Ci}(-2\pi+iz) = 0$$

where

$$\text{Ci}(z) = -\int_z^\infty \frac{\cos(t)}{t} dt$$

Mathematica doesn't simplify this to zero. Graphing it appears to produce the zero function, everywhere I look in $\mathbb{C}$. I have never seen this property before. Does anyone know if it is true and/or where a reference would be? Considering it's simplicity, I would have thought this would be on wikipedia, but didn't see it on there.

Comment: For a counterexample try $z \in \mathbb{R}^{-}$, e.g. $z = -1$ gives you [$2 \cdot \pi = 0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%CF%80+%E2%88%92+i+CosIntegral%5B2%CF%80%E2%88%92iz%5D+%2B+i+CosIntegral%5B-2%CF%80%2Biz%5D+where+z%3D-1).

Comment: If $z$ is an arbitrary complex number, you can rewrite $w=2\pi-iz$ with arbitrary complex $w$, and $\mathrm{Ci}(w)-\mathrm{Ci}(-w)=i\pi$. But if it's true for $w$, it can't be true for $-w$. It seems to be correct for $\mathrm{Im}(w)>0$ or $\mathrm{Im}(w)=0$ and $\mathrm{Re}(w)<0$.

Comment: Yes, it does appear that $z\in (-\infty,0]$ yields $2\pi$. Let me update.

Comment: For the record, for `simplify(Pi-I*Ci(2*Pi-I*z)+I*Ci(-2*Pi+I*z));` Maple returns $\pi(1-\mathrm{csgn}(2i\pi+z))$, and $\mathrm{csgn}$ is defined [here](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=csgn).

Comment: By the uniqueness theorem, this would appear to suggest that Ci is not analytic on the imaginary axis. In any case, it is interesting that Maple simplifies this.

Comment: The problem lies at $0$, then you need a branch cut. For $\mathrm{Ci}(z)$ you have a logarithmic term, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Cosine_integral

Comment: Yes, but log would normally only exclude a branch, not cause two half planes to have different constant values. It is still surprising to be that this is constant (even if different constants in two half planes). Wasn't expecting that.

Comment: But here you are basically considering $\mathrm{Ci}(z)-\mathrm{Ci}(-z)$, not just $\mathrm{Ci}(z)$. You would get the same phenomenon with $\log(z)-\log(-z)$.

Comment: There is an even function $F$ st $Ci(w)=\log w + F(w)$ whenever $w \notin (-\infty, 0]$ where $\log w$ is the principal one; but then $Ci(w)-Ci(-w)=\log (w)-\log (-w)$ which has exactly this behavior

Comment: oh right, there are two logarithms. thanks for the clarification. it makes way more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, your formula is only correct for $z \in \mathbb{R}_{0}^{+}$. But we can quickly extend it for negative $z$ as well, since:
$$
\begin{align*}
\pi - \operatorname{Ci}\left( 2 \cdot \pi - z \cdot i \right) \cdot i + \operatorname{Ci}\left( -2 \cdot \pi + z \cdot i \right) \cdot i &= \begin{cases} 0,\, &\text{if}\, z \in \mathbb{R}_{0}^{+}\\ 2 \cdot \pi,\, &\text{if}\, z \in \mathbb{R}^{-}\\ \end{cases}\\
\pi - \operatorname{Ci}\left( 2 \cdot \pi - z \cdot i \right) \cdot i + \operatorname{Ci}\left( -2 \cdot \pi + z \cdot i \right) \cdot i &= 2 \cdot \pi \cdot \theta\left( -x \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$
where $\theta\left( \cdot \right)$ is the unit step function aka the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

Why is that? For the proof we can first state that the equation should result in a constant $c$. And we know $\frac{\operatorname{d}\text{costant}}{\operatorname{d}z} = 0 \wedge \frac{\operatorname{d}\operatorname{Ci}\left( z \right)}{\operatorname{d}z} = \frac{\cos\left( z \right)}{z}$, so the derivative of the reflection formula should also be $0$ if it is constant per interval - wich is ture as you can see [here](https://www.ableitungsrechner.net/#expr=%CF%80%E2%88%92expintegral_ci%282%E2%8B%85%CF%80%E2%88%92z%E2%8B%85i%29%E2%8B%85i%2Bexpintegral_ci%28%E2%88%922%E2%8B%85%CF%80%2Bz%E2%8B%85i%29%E2%8B%85i&diffvar=z).

I got the claim that $\pi - \operatorname{Ci}\left( 2 \cdot \pi - z \cdot i \right) \cdot i + \operatorname{Ci}\left( -2 \cdot \pi + z \cdot i \right) \cdot i = 2 \cdot \pi \cdot \theta\left( -x \right)$ holds from the graphs. Let's assume that's it, we should be able to just solve for $z$ and get that. But why make it so difficult? We already know that $+\pi$ doesn't change anything about the interval distributions and $\operatorname{Ci}\left( \pm x \cdot i \mp 2 \cdot \pi \right) + \operatorname{Ci}\left( \mp x \cdot i \pm 2 \cdot \pi \right)$ is not continuous only at $x = 0$ (when $x \in \mathbb{R}$) aka it should only have at least two intervals give in which the function is non-equal. So there is a constant for negative $z$ and one for positive $z$. As you have already observed, a value for positive $z$ is $0$ and since it is constant it must be so for every single one else when $z > 0$. Doing the same for negative $z$ ($z < 0$) as I did in my comment we get $2 \cdot \pi$ which is the solution from before aka we derived the formula.

Comment: I get zero still:
\[Pi] - I CosIntegral[2 \[Pi] - I x] +   I CosIntegral[-2 \[Pi] + I x] /. x -> 1.0 + I

Comment: Oh... I deleted the teext with my typo: You're right.